# Cast from '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

This line  `let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! NSDictionary`  I get a warning: `Cast from '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails`

I try to use `let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<NSObject: AnyObject>` replace `let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! NSDictionary`. But I get an error :`Expected '>' to complete generic argument list`. How to fix the warning.

Xcode 7.1  OS X Yosemite

This is my code:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! NSDictionary //warning

    let keyboardBounds = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let duration = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
    let keyboardBoundsRect = self.view.convertRect(keyboardBounds, toView: nil)

    let keyboardInputViewFrame = self.finishView!.frame

    let deltaY = keyboardBoundsRect.size.height

    let animations: (()->Void) = {

        self.finishView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -deltaY)
    }

    if duration > 0 {



    } else {

        animations()
    }


}
```

Comment: Just use Swift native dictionary

Comment: I try to use `let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<NSObject: AnyObject>`  but it is wrong, I get an error.

Comment: Why type casting at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSNotification's userInfo property is already defined as a(n optional) dictionary.

So you don't need to cast it at all, just unwrap it.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        ...
    }
}
```

all the rest of your code should work as is.

Comment: Unwrapping is the main thing the author needs to take away from this; you can't cast `[NSObject : AnyObject]?` to `NSDictionary` because the former is optional and the latter isn't. You could cast to `NSDictionary?` or you could unwrap and cast to `NSDictionary`. But, as you say, in practice you just need to unwrap and then you can use it natively without bridging back to the Objective-C type.

Comment: I got it. It's vary kind of you.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to force cast an optional to an NSDictionary. Try:

```
let userInfo = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I tried. It's also OK. I think  Tristan Burnside's answer is more reasonable.